# sharing config elements between different test plans

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter I have different Test Plans that use webservices from the same provider. Because of provider's configuration I have to add same Config Elements in each of my Test Plans. Is there any way I can share Config Elements, so that there is no duplication?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can share by reading same file with [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
2. Use [Property File Reader](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/) plugin
3. Read properties file via Beanshell Sampler:

   FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("d:/somefolder/somefile.properties"));
   props.load(is);
   is.close();
4. add `-q` option to load another property file

Comment: This only helps in sharing the same test data. The question is can we share elements of a test plan. Is there a way to make a common set of test plans and reuse them.